# Is there any way to prevent villagers claiming workstations?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm building a villager breeder in Minecraft Bedrock 1.18. I want all the babies in a holding area until they grow up, then I'll grab one of them with a minecart and start his *onboarding training* to his new job. But I need to ensure that the workstation I place is claimed by that villager on the minecart, and not other villager still in the holding area.

**Is there any way to prevent them to claim *any* job?**

I know that in Bedrock edition villagers need a bed before they can work, but since this will be built in my breeder, they'll all have their own bed.

So far I've tried placing the villagers in water (only their feet), and making the workstation unreacheable - I built a 3x3x3 iron block cube with the lectern inside, a few blocks appart from the villager, no way he can access or even see it... but he still claimed it. I've also tried pushing a glass block (regular and tinted) into the villager's head with a piston - no luck either.

I could place the *onboarding facility* far away from the breeder and it would solve the problem. But I'd just rather have both at the same building if it's possible.

I could also just place a few workstations, until I see the green particles around *my* villager. But with lecterns you always have to reshuffle them a gazillion times until you get the right trade, and sometimes when you do that, the villagers decide to swap workplaces, which gets really annoying.

Comment: Not the solution you are looking for, but... why don't you place only one workstation at a time? In this way you are sure that the villager will claim only the brand new free workstation.

Comment: @pinckerman I would, if it wasn't because sometimes when you re-place the workstation (or push it with a piston), the villagers swap workplaces, so the lectern I'm moving no longer reshuffles my villager trades, since he's claimed a different one now. It's very annoying. I guess I'll have to use 2 buildings instead :(

Comment: Indeed, lectern are a pain in the... you should start with them, so your villagers could only swap between librarians. Then add remaining workstations